# WebView videos on fullscreen

Tags: java, android

Please see below my code: I have tried several codes that fulllscreen for videos and I did not succeed, or I did not know how to install.

I need enable fullscreen for videos for any player video

[image: I need to leave enabled this print]

```
 package com.androidapp.www.WEBSITE;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.webkit.WebSettings;
 import android.webkit.WebView;
 import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {


WebView wv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings settings = wv.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.loadUrl("https://www.mfshd.net");
    wv.setWebViewClient(new MobWebViewClient());
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if(wv.canGoBack()){

        wv.goBack();

    }else{

        super.onBackPressed();

    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private class MobWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {


}



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have to add a FrameLayout in your ***activity_main*** and make its visibility "gone"

Secondly add this code to your MainActivity:

```
    private View mCustomView;
    private WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback mCustomViewCallback;

    wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

            @Override
            public void onShowCustomView(View view, CustomViewCallback callback) {
                super.onShowCustomView(view, callback);
                // if a view already exists then immediately terminate the new one
                if (mCustomView != null) {
                    callback.onCustomViewHidden();
                    return;
                }
                mCustomView = view;
                wv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                frameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                frameLayout.addView(view);
                mCustomViewCallback = callback;

            }

            @Override
            public void onHideCustomView() {
                super.onHideCustomView();

                if (mCustomView == null)
                    return;

                wv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                frameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                // Hide the custom view.
                mCustomView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                // Remove the custom view from its container.
                frameLayout.removeView(mCustomView);
                mCustomViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();

                mCustomView = null;

            }
        });
```

Comment: I am not able to implement, if I pass all the code you could insert? I really need the videos to be open in fullscreen, because the fullscreen button does not work

Comment: Sure I can help you

Comment: this is the source "http://www.mediafire.com/file/wje6bvtcmpbwquf/website-to-android.rar/file"